# How do I $_REQUEST an option made by a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, request

The type of sport-options are selected from a database where I have all the type of sports. 
Type_sport contains the name of the sport. Everything works great and all the sports in the database are shown in an option list. But how do I $_REQUEST what type of sport the user have choosen when the options are comming from a database?
The code in the form looks like this:

```
    <p>Choose sport: </p>
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
   <select name="sports">
        <option>Choose sport</option>
            <?php
            $db=mysqli_connect("xxxxxxxx","xxxxx","","xxxxx");
            $sql="Select* from sports";
            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            $numberOfRows=mysqli_affected_rows($db);
            for($i=0;$i<$numberOfRows;$i++){
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            echo "<option> ".$row["type_sport"]."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

I have tried: `$sport=$_REQUEST["sports"];` but it does not work.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the option tag a value attribute that's the only way you'll get the value from the request superglobal `echo "<option value='".$row["type_sport"]."'> ".$row["type_sport"]."</option>";`

Comment: It does not work when I use  $sport=$_REQUEST["sports"];

Comment: Did you add the value attribute?

Comment: Yes. I copied and pasted what you wrote. Hopefully it's nothing wrong with that code.

Comment: You might also want to check if there is a column called 'type_sport' in your database 'sports' table

Comment: I haven't. I also tried to change to <select name="sports2"> but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Does it change anything if you fetch_assoc instead of fetch_array?

Comment: Also what happens when you print_r($_POST); ?

Comment: I tried fetch_assoc and it was the same. Did not work. But what do you mean with the print_r($_POST);

Comment: print the array to see if you're actually getting data

Comment: Yes it prints all the other stuff from my form (name, adress, telephone etc), but not the information about type of sport from the select options.

Comment: Could you dump the `$row` variable to see whether there is a key `type_sport`?